# Convert this query to eloquent

Tags: mysql, laravel, eloquent, str-to-date

I'm a noob in Laravel. can anyone help me write this query in eloquent

```
SELECT
    *
FROM
    table
WHERE
    (
        STR_TO_DATE(`date`, '%m/%d/%Y') BETWEEN '2014-08-05'
        AND '2014-08-05'
    )

ORDER BY
    id
```

Comment: If you don't want to learn - hire someone, as you do when your car is broken or when you have toothache.

Comment: We are not here to do your work. Please read the manual and lets us see what you have tried.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to use your query as is, just use DB::raw

http://laravel.com/docs/queries#raw-expressions

```
DB::raw(SELECT * FROM table WHERE ( STR_TO_DATE(date, '%m/%d/%Y') BETWEEN '2014-08-05' AND '2014-08-05' ) ORDER BY id);
```

Answer (score 2):

Well making the assumption that your model is called `Table`, if your field is of type `DATE`, you can do this:

```
Table::where('date', '>=', '2014-08-05')
    ->where('date', '=<', '2014-08-05')
    ->get();
```

Alternatively you can do:

```
Table::select('table.*', DB::raw("STR_TO_DATE(date, '%m/%d/%Y') as date_format"))
    ->where('date_format', '>=', '2014-08-05')
    ->where('date_format', '=<', '2014-08-05')
    ->get();
```

Comment: Just tested it on Laravel, it bring back: SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'date_format' in 'field list'

Answer (score 0):

You may try this:

```
$from = '...';
$to = '...';

DB::table('table')->whereBetween('date', array($from, $to))->get();
```

Or using Eloquent:

```
ModelName::whereBetween('date', array($from, $to))->get();
```